# Can I perform a Left Join on Primary Keys in a subquery?

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join

I have a question about a SQL query I am writing in Microsoft Access. I have two tables that include a version of a primary key that I am trying to join them on.

The first table (Table1) includes the PK # in this format: TORD46709NVSW. The last four characters can range from 3-4 letters and have many combinations.

The second table (Table 2) includes the PK # in this format: TORD00046709. There are always three zeroes after TORD (these 4 characters are always consistent).

I have written queries to get these two to the following format: TORD46709.

Table 1:

```
SELECT

 LEFT ([PKT_NUMBER_SFX], 9) AS

TORD_NUMBER

FROM Table_1;
```

Table 2:

```
SELECT

LEFT ([Transfer ID], 4) +

RIGHT ([Transfer ID], 5)

AS

TORD_NUMBER

FROM Table_2;
```

My issues is that I'm now trying to join these two tables, but am struggling. I am trying to write the above statements in a subquery in order to join but am now thinking I might need to do an update table query before joining. I would like to avoid the latter.

```
SELECT QlikView_Report.PKT_NUMBER_SFX, Transfer_Orders_OLD.[Transfer ID]
FROM QlikView_Report 
LEFT JOIN TORD_REPORT ON QlikView_Report.PKT_NUMBER_SFX = Transfer_Orders_OLD.[Transfer ID]
WHERE Transfer ID IN 
(SELECT
LEFT ([Transfer ID], 4) +
RIGHT ([Transfer ID], 5)
AS
TORD_NUMBER
FROM Transfer_Orders_OLD) AND  
(SELECT 
 LEFT ([PKT_NUMBER_SFX], 9) AS
TORD_NUMBER 
FROM QlikView_Report);
```

Let me know if you think it possible to join on these non-matching PK's.

Comment: If this is something you do often, or if the table1 is extremely large you should consider getting the table2 key into the table1 table, where it can take advantage of indexes.  Joining two tables on calculated keys is inefficient and large queries can get very slow.  But if it's just a one-off and your table is less than a few hundred thousand rows then don't bother.

Comment: Table 1 is around 75-80k rows give or take as it changes over time. I don't see it growing to over a few hundred thousand rows, so would it still run fairly quickly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed table name from `QlikView_Report` to `QlikView_Report_OG` in from clause.

```
SELECT QlikView_Report_OG.[Pkt Ctl #], QlikView_Report_OG.[Customer PO], QlikView_Report_OG.[PKT_NUMBER_SFX], Transfer_Orders_OLD.[Origin], 
Transfer_Orders_OLD.[Destination], Transfer_Orders_OLD.[Status], QlikView_Report_OG.[Item Desc], 
QlikView_Report_OG.[Qty], QlikView_Report_OG.[Carton Number], QlikView_Report_OG.[Carton Status],
QlikView_Report_OG.[Load Number], QlikView_Report_OG.[Wave Number], QlikView_Report_OG.[Carton Tracking], 
QlikView_Report_OG.[Cancellation], QlikView_Report_OG.[Trailer #] FROM QlikView_Report_OG 
LEFT JOIN Transfer_Orders_OLD 
ON LEFT (QlikView_Report.PKT_NUMBER_SFX, 9) = (LEFT (Transfer_Orders_OLD.[Transfer ID], 4) + RIGHT (Transfer_Orders_OLD.[Transfer ID], 5));
```

Comment: Ahh, great catch. Thank you, Kazi! I also updated the QlikViewReport to the OG version after the ON LEFT command. This is working nicely for me now! Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any subquery but need to compare both columns within on clause of left join.
Please try this.

```
    SELECT QlikView_Report.PKT_NUMBER_SFX, Transfer_Orders_OLD.[Transfer ID]
    FROM QlikView_Report 
    LEFT JOIN Transfer_Orders_OLD 
    ON LEFT (QlikView_Report.PKT_NUMBER_SFX, 9) = (LEFT (Transfer_Orders_OLD.[Transfer ID], 4) + RIGHT (Transfer_Orders_OLD.[Transfer ID], 5));
```

For which rows condition would match you will get data in both the columns if condition don't match then data will be available only in PKT_NUMBER_SFX column.

I have checked the query in **MS Access** database and it's working as desired.

Comment: That worked! Now I'm trying to pull in specific columns from each report and am getting dialogue box pop-ups. Will include code in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of a subquery. Use the calculation directly in the join condition.
Try this,

```
SELECT 
q.PKT_NUMBER_SFX
, t.[Transfer ID]

FROM 
QlikView_Report q
LEFT JOIN 
Transfer_Orders_OLD t

ON LEFT (q.[PKT_NUMBER_SFX], 9) = (LEFT (t.[Transfer ID], 4) +RIGHT (t.[Transfer 
ID], 5))
```